# Accessing object member in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi I know there is plenty information in the web how to access objects in javascript objects. But those examples didn't help with the object in a format returned by the console `node = xpath.select("//unit/object[@name='parProgramModeDefault']/@comment",doc);`

When printed into the console the object looks like this:

`console.log(res);`:

[image]

How to access `nodeName` for example? This `res.nodeName` returns `undefined`

Comment: There's no generic solution and it has nothing to do with the console. You need to look to the documentation of the xpath module you are using, in order to learn how to use its return values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this specific instance, it's returning and you're logging an array, where the first (and only) entry in that array appears to be an object of type `Attr`.  You can access `nodeName` via `res[0].nodeName`.

Answer (score 1):

pick up first array `res[0].propertyName` or you can do same by looping too